# Excel VBA - Check duplicate entries and copy from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 the column values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to accomplish an "easy" task with excel which is:

1. Let the user input a numeric value into column D (starting from row 3) of `SheetA`.
2. I want Excel to double check if the entry is a duplicate within column D. If it is, a warning message should be fired and the entry is cancelled.
3. If the entry is not a duplicate, then the new value should be copied into the same row, but Column A, of `SheetB`.

This is the code I am using:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, msg As String, x As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Columns(4), Target) 'Column to check duplicate

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rng
            If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then
                If Application.CountIf(Columns(4), r.Value) > 1 Then 'Column to check duplicate...the last number remains 1
                    msg = msg & vbLf & vbTab
                    If x Is Nothing Then
                        r.Activate
                        Set x = r
                    Else
                        Set x = Union(x, r)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If Len(msg) Then
            MsgBox "You have entered a duplicate EID" & msg
            x.ClearContents
            x.Select
        End If

        Set rng = Nothing
        Set x = Nothing
        Sheets("BSheet").Range("A3:A1048576").ClearContents
        ASheet.Select

        Dim EID As String 'define the column heading as a variable
        Dim lastrow As Long 'define the last row

        lastrow = ASheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row 'this will give us the column number in ASheet

        For i = 3 To lastrow 'here you say that 3rd row is going to be the 1st row to copy
            EID = ASheet.Cells(i, 4) 'here you say that 4th column is going to be the column to copy
            BSheet.Activate
            erow = BSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row 'this stay at 1
            BSheet.Cells(erow, 1) = EID 'this stays at 1
            ASheet.Activate
        Next i

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help with this one.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

For Duplication control its more efficient to use the above, then you can proceed with macro to copy the range needed.

Hope that works for you

Comment: The only thing with the above method is that it doesn't work if a value is pasted in the column while this is essential. This is why I wanted to proceed with VBA . The above code works on file but not in another if a copy the code and pasted in another worksheet. This makes me think that there is something I am missing that I cannot figure out. Could someone give it a test and please suggest me how to proceed? Thanks